# Translation of "as far as I know/understand/remember"

Tags: traduction, subjonctif

What is the translation of the phrase "As far as I know/understand/remember"?

Google Translate has

> Pour autant que je sache
>
> Pour autant que je comprends
>
> Pour autant que je me souviens

I was able to verify the first in a dictionary, but not the other two. Should they instead use the subjunctive "comprenne" and "me souvienne"? Why would the subjunctive be the correct choice for this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you could not find them is that the construction requires the subjonctive ("je sache").

> Pour autant que je sache,
>
> Pour autant que je me souvienne,

Or if you remember something ("se souvenir **de** qqch"):

> Pour autant que je m'en souvienne,

For "comprendre": I cannot fault the phrase "pour autant que je comprenne", but it does not sound colloquial. I would definitely say:

> Dans ma compréhension,
>
> Si j'ai bien compris,
>
> Si je comprends bien,

In spoken language, however, you could say:

> Pour ce que j'en sais,
>
> Pour ce que je m'en souviens,
>
> Pour ce que j'en comprends,

In my own experience, the first is frequent, the last two are a little more clunky.

I do not see any deep truth here, it is just a matter of common usage.